# API gateway returns 401 and doesn't invoke custom authorizer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've implemented a custom 'REQUEST' type authorizer for an API gateway which validates a JWT token passed in the 'Authorization' header.  I've tested the lambda independently and it works as expected. I've also attached the authorizer to my routes and I can test it in the AWS console - again, everything seems to work (see image):

[successful invoke via console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET9zj.png)

However, when I try to invoke my endpoints with the token in the `Authorization` header, I always receive an UNAUTHORIZED response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "category": "ClientError",
      "code": "UNAUTHORIZED",
      "detail": "Unauthorized",
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/cases",
      "requestId": "004eb254-a926-45ad-96a5-ce3527621c81",
      "retryable": false
    }
  ]
}
```

From what I have gathered, API gateway never invokes my Authorizer as i don't see any log events in its cloudwatch.  I was able to enable cloudwatch logging of my API gateway, and the only log information I see is as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   timestamp   |                                                                                                                             message                                                                                                                              |
|---------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1578275720543 | (dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c) Extended Request Id: F2v9WFfiIAMF-9w=                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| 1578275720543 | (dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c) Unauthorized request: dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c                                                                                                                                                                |
| 1578275720543 | (dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c) Extended Request Id: F2v9WFfiIAMF-9w=                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| 1578275720544 | (dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c) Gateway response type: UNAUTHORIZED with status code: 401                                                                                                                                                                 |
| 1578275720544 | (dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c) Gateway response body: {"errors": [{"category": "ClientError","code": "UNAUTHORIZED","detail": "Unauthorized","method": "GET","path": "/cases","requestId": "dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c","retryable": false }]} |
| 1578275720544 | (dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c) Gateway response headers: {}                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1578275720544 | (dac0d4f6-1380-4049-bcee-bf776ca78e5c) Gateway response type: UNAUTHORIZED with status code: 401                                                                                                                                                                 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

At this point I am completely stuck and not sure how to debug this further.  I'm assuming something must be configured wrong but the log information I can find doesn't given any indication of what the problem is.  I've also pasted a copy of my authorizers configuration in the image below:

[Authorizer Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRVny.png)

[Screenshot of one endpoint configured to use the authorizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAdLg.png)

Comment: Please post your authorizer code. I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: @ArunK i've added my authorizer handler to the post, but I'm confused how the code could be the problem here.  As I said in my original post, The authorizer works when i invoke it as a lambda and also when I test it from the API gateway authorizer console, and it is never invoked when i make a request to the endpoints via Curl or postman.

Comment: are you using serverless framework. i dont think so ?

Comment: did you confgure the authorizer lambda as the authorizer to any api

Comment: I am using serverless framework but I am manually deploying the shared authorizer so that I can get around the limitation here:
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#note-while-using-authorizers-with-shared-api-gateway

I can post the cloudformation if you think it is relevant.  I've attached the authorizer to many of my endpoints and they all show the same behavior.

Comment: please attach the screenshot where you configured the api endpoint to use your custom authorizer

Comment: @ArunK i've added the image

Comment: i would deploy the authorizer part of a serverless stack and configure it as authorizer for an api end point, then you can compare the differences. just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem I was having:
I needed to set identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization in the authorizer field of the endpoint as well as in the CF stack.

Custom Authorizer definition in raw cloudformation:

```
service: 
  name: api-base

frameworkVersion: ">=1.2.0 <2.0.0"

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-optimize
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  stage: ${self:provider.stage, 'dev'}
  serverless-offline:
    port: ${env:OFFLINE_PORT, '4000'}
  false: false
  cognitoStack: marley-auth
  customDomain:
    domainName: ${env:BE_HOST, ''}
    enabled: ${env:EN_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, self:custom.false}
    stage: ${self:provider.stage, 'dev'}
    createRoute53Record: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  versionFunctions: true
  apiName: public
  logs:
    restApi: true
  stackTags:
      COMMIT_SHA: ${env:COMMIT_SHA, 'NO-SHA'}
  environment:
    USER_POOL_ID: ${cf:${self:custom.cognitoStack}-${self:custom.stage}.UserPoolId}
    CLIENT_ID: ${cf:${self:custom.cognitoStack}-${self:custom.stage}.UserPoolClientId}
  timeout: 30
  iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
      - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    Resource: "*"

functions:
  authorizer:
    handler: handler/authorize.handler

resources:
  - Outputs:
      ApiGatewayRestApiId:
        Value:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Export:
          Name: ${self:custom.stage}-${self:provider.apiName}-ApiGatewayRestApiId
      ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId:
        Value:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - ApiGatewayRestApi
            - RootResourceId 
        Export:
          Name: ${self:custom.stage}-${self:provider.apiName}-ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId
      SharedAuthorizerId:
        Value:
          Ref: SharedAuthorizer
        Export:
          Name: ${self:custom.stage}-${self:provider.apiName}-ApiGatewaySharedAuthorizerId
  - Resources:
      SharedAuthorizer:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
        Properties:
          Name: public
          AuthorizerUri: !Join 
            - ''
            - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
              - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
              - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
              - !GetAtt 
                - AuthorizerLambdaFunction
                - Arn
              - /invocations
          RestApiId: !Ref 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
          Type: REQUEST
          IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
          AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: '300'
        DependsOn: AuthorizerLambdaFunction
      ApiAuthLambdaPermission:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
        Properties:
          Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
          FunctionName: !Ref AuthorizerLambdaFunction
          Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
          SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:#{ApiGatewayRestApi}/authorizers/*"
        DependsOn: ApiGatewayRestApi
```

Using the authorizer in another stack - note that I have specified `IdentitySource` here as well as in the definition of the authorizer - for some reason I had to do it in both places.

```
authorizer:
  type: CUSTOM
  authorizerId: ${cf:api-base-${self:custom.stage}.SharedAuthorizerId}
  identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
```

Comment: Please update this response to very clearly show the changes that you made, then mark this question as "closed."  The next poor soul who runs into this same problem will thank you ...